# Importrange in googlesheets is limited to 60 Columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, col

I have this problem (QUERY(IMPORTRANGE while I'm adding columns like Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 and when it reaches Col61 it shows an error.

**Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col61**

So basically, all columns from 61 and so on is like unaccesible or in other term, it is limited to 60 Cols only?

Heres my Code:

```
=(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link","Sheet1!A2:BH3008"),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,
Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,
Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col25,Col26,Col27,Col28,Col29,Col30,
Col31,Col32,Col33,Col34,Col35,Col36,Col37,Col38,Col39,Col40,
Col41,Col42,Col43,Col44,Col45,Col46,Col47,Col48,Col49,Col50,
Col51,Col52,Col53,Col54,Col55,Col56,Col57,Col58,Col59,Col60,
Col61,Col62,Col63,Col64,Col65,Col66,Col67,Col68,Col69,Col70,
Col71,Col72,Col73,Col74,Col75,Col76,Col77,Col78 where Col41='CJ'", 0))
```

When I remove Col61 to Col78 it works, when I make a separate code for 61 like this, it still doesn't work. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated! Check this two sample shortcode Below.

```
=(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link","Endorsements!A2:BH3008"),"select Col61 where Col41='CJ'", 0))


=(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link","Endorsements!A2:BH3008"),"select 
Col61,Col62,Col63,Col64,Col65,Col66,Col67,Col68,Col69,Col70 where Col41='CJ'", 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is right. you dont have more than 60 columns in range `A:BH`

column A is `Col1`

and column BH is `Col60`

you can test this with his formula in any cell:

```
=COLUMN(BH1)
```

if you want Col61 your range needs to be `A:BI`

Comment: so, the code should be, "Sheet1!A2:BI3008" or above. Thank you, I almost got loss there. heheh.

Comment: @AngeloDelaCruz A:BI if you want Col61, A:BK if you want Col62, A:BK if you want Col63, etc